# QML Moving text with timer

Tags: qt, qml

I need to create moving text on the screen continuously from right to left, I have implemented it using `QML` `Timer` and `Text` element.

The below code works fine but I am concerned about the below code causing more  cpu or memory usage mainly because the timer is triggered every 33 ms. I have to use this in my places in my application and in multiple instances, like inside many grid windows.

Is this right approach? or does anything exist better than this?

```
Rectangle{
        width:parent.width
        height:parent.height
        color: "#333333"

        Timer {
            id: resetTimer
            interval: 33
            repeat: true
            running: true
            onTriggered: {
             console.log("triggred");
             moving_text.x = moving_text.x-1
             if(moving_text.x<-1*moving_text.paintedWidth)
               moving_text.x=parent.width
            }
        }

        Text{
            id:moving_text
            x:parent.width
            text:"Moving text"
            color: "white"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why to make things so complected. You could use `NumberAnimation` on `x` as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle{
    id: root
    width:250
    height:250
    color: "#333333"

    Text{
        id:moving_text
        x:parent.width
        text:"Moving text"
        color: "white"

        NumberAnimation on x{
            from: root.width
            to: -1*moving_text.width
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            duration: 3000
        }
    }
}
```

As for your concern about memory and cpu usage, you should compare both the methods and check which one suits you. But my personal recommendation is to use `NumberAnimation`.