# QML continuouse infinite moving text

Tags: qt, qml

I need to implement infinite moving text but before it wraps around, same text should be displayed at the end.

There is already a solved question [QML Moving text with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665098/qml-moving-text-with-timer), but my problem is different.

Example:

My text is "some text" and I want achive animation like this

```
Frame    I need this     Regular NumberAnimation
0        |some text |    |some text |
10       |ome text  |    |ome text  |
20       |me text   |    |me text   |
30       |e text   s|    |e text    |
40       | text   so|    | text     |
50       |text   som|    |text      |
60       |ext   some|    |ext       |
70       |xt   some |    |xt        |
80       |t   some t|    |t         |
90       |   some te|    |          |
100      |  some tex|    |         s|
110      | some text|    |        so|
120      |some text |    |       som|
130      |ome text  |    |      some|
140      |me text   |    |     some |
150      |e text   s|    |    some t|
160      | text   so|    |   some te|
170      |text   som|    |  some tex|
180      |ext   some|    | some text|
190      |xt   some |    |some text |
200      |t   some t|    |ome text  |
```

Is there an easy way how to do this in QML?

Comment: How about doing the regular NumberAnimation but instead of having "some text" you have "some text    some text" ?

Comment: @dydil I have corrected the question. I need infinite animation. Your proposal just moves the same problem after the next copy of the text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it without any animation whatsoever, simply compose the display string by cutting the source string at a specific step:

```
  Item {
    property string text: "some text"
    property string spacing: "      "
    property string combined: text + spacing
    property string display: combined.substring(step) + combined.substring(0, step)
    property int step: 0

    Timer {
      interval: 200
      running: true
      repeat: true
      onTriggered: parent.step = (parent.step + 1) % parent.combined.length
    }

    Text {
      text: parent.display
    }
  }
```

This is lighter than doing position animation, plus it has a more "organic" look IMO.

But if you still insist on animation, you can simply have two text elements in a row to fake wrapping over. But that will be heavier than the previous solution, as it will involve many more reevaluations for sub-pixel animation, two text elements and also the graphics clipping that will be necessary to hide the "offscreen" text:

```
  Item {
    id: root
    property alias text: t1.text
    property int spacing: 30
    width: t1.width + spacing
    height: t1.height
    clip: true

    Text {
      id: t1
      text: "some text"
      NumberAnimation on x { running: true; from: 0; to: -root.width; duration: 3000; loops: Animation.Infinite }

      Text {
        x: root.width
        text: t1.text
      }
    }
  }
```

The two implementations side by side:

[image]

Comment: Which implementation you show on the left and which on the right in you `gif`?

Comment: The left is the animation, the right is the string splitting.

Comment: Do you have an idea about the cost for the text layout? I think I somewhere read something along the lines "When the text changes, it needs to be relaid out". I have no idea how that applies here, and how the cost relates to those of the clipping and sub-pixel animation. Also: What would you think about a shader?

Comment: Yes, a shader approach will work as well, it is basically the first solution, but instead of splitting and composing the text you will be splitting and composing the pixel data in a trivial shader.

Comment: On my PC 1000 of them animated texts eat up about 5% CPU, whereas 1000 of the first implementation keep steady at 1%. So there you have it, bout 5 times more efficient CPU wise, and probably even more GPU efficient as well, since you have a lot less updates :)

Comment: @derM keep in mind that a shader approach will simply move the overhead to mostly GPU memory (the actual shader overhead will be negligible), and while the first approach will easily handle text of indefinite size with minor tweaks, the shader approach will be limited depending on how much of a buffer the GPU is capable of providing.

Comment: The first solution is ugly for all non monospace fonts. So for me, the second solution is the right one.